# Declarables and MultiRabbit

Tags: spring, spring-rabbit, multirabbitmq

I'm using spring-multirabbit library :

```
rabbitmq:
    host: localhost
    port: 5672
    username: guest
    password: guest
  multirabbitmq:
    enabled: true
    connections:
      my-rabbitmq:
        host: localhost
        port: 5677
        username: guest
        password: guest
```

How can I make sure that the "Declarables" act only on a specific rabbit connection and not on all the declared rabbits connections ?

```
@Bean
public Declarables queues(MessagingProperties props) {
       Declaradles declarables = /* build declarables...? */
       return declarables;
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok.. I figured out how to solve it

Specify the admin with method : 'setAdminsThatShouldDeclare' on the declarable :

```
@Bean
public Declarables queues(MessagingProperties messagingProperties) {
    return new Declarables(messagingProperties.getBindings().stream().map(b ->
    {
        Declarable queue = QueueBuilder.nonDurable(b.getQueue()).build();
        queue.setAdminsThatShouldDeclare("my-rabbitmq-admin");
        return queue;
    }).collect(Collectors.toList()));
}
```

Comment: You should accept your own answer.